# Camera captured image is not showing in UICollectionVIew, how to display images captured from UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, avfoundation

I have been trying to display and store camera captured images in `UICollectionView`, But somehow `UICollectionView` not displaying the images from the camera, I checked the `self.images.count` in

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return images.count 
}
```

it is returning the number of taken images, but somehow, `UICollectionView` is empty..

I did
 `self.imgCollectionView.reloadData()` and
connected the `dataSource` and `delegate`.. .

Inside the

### `ViewController_1.swift`

```
 let cameraAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "upload", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
 let cameraUpload = UIAlertAction.init(title: "upload from camera", style: .default, handler: {_ in
    
     self.uploadFromCamera()
        
})

  func uploadFromCamera() {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable( .camera) {
         let cameraPicker = UIImagePickerController()
         cameraPicker.delegate = self
         cameraPicker.sourceType = .camera
         cameraPicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
         self.navigationController?.present(cameraPicker, animated: true, completion: nil )
      }
  }


  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
         if let pickedIMG = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
           if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CapturedPhotoViewController") as? CapturedPhotoViewController {
                 vc.images.append(pickedIMG)
                 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
             }
         }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

### CollectionViewController.swift

```
class CapturedPhotoViewController: UIViewController {
   
 @IBOutlet weak var imgCollectionView: UICollectionView!
  var images: [UIImage] = []
  
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.imgCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return images.count 
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CapturedPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! CapturedPhotoCell
        let imgContent = self.images[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.configure(image: imgContent)
        return cell
    }
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
}

class CapturedPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    func configure(image: UIImage) {
        self.imageView.image = image
        
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker will allow you to select multiple images. \n
2. https://github.com/suzuki-0000/SKPhotoBrowser contains the source code to display images on UICollectionView, it will also give you an answer to how to display each image on full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.. now it works.. .

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func showImagePickerOptions() {
        let cameraAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "upload", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
        let cameraUpload = UIAlertAction.init(title: "upload from camera", style: .default, handler: {_ in
            self.showPickerController(sourceType: .camera)
        })
        let libraryUpload = UIAlertAction.init(title: "upload from library", style: .default, handler: {_ in
            self.showPickerController(sourceType: .photoLibrary)
        })
       
        cameraAlert.addActions(actions: [cameraUpload, libraryUpload])
        self.navigationController?.present(cameraAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func showPickerController(sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
        let pickerController: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.allowsEditing = true
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = sourceType
        self.navigationController?.present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            if let vc =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CapturedPhotoViewController") as? CapturedPhotoViewController {
                vc.title = "image Selection"
                vc.images = self.images
                DDLogDebug("CapturedImageVC image count:\(vc.images.count)")
                self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        })
        guard let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage else {
           DDLogDebug("No image.. . \nSomething went wrong in < didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo > ")
            return
        }
        self.images.append(image)
       // print imageSize and imageCount to check if it is nil or not.. .
        print(image.size)
        print(self.images.count)
        
    }
}
```

CollectionViewVC:

```
class CapturedPhotoViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var imgCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var images: [UIImage]!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
   
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.images?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CapturedPhotoCell", for: indexPath) as! CapturedPhotoCell
        guard let imageContent = self.images?[indexPath.row] else {
            DDLogDebug("Image content is nil.. .")
            return cell
        }
        
        cell.configure(image: imageContent)
        return cell
    }
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
}

extension CapturedPhotoViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        return CGSize(width: (screenWidth/4) - 8, height: (screenWidth/4) - 8)
            
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 7, left: 7, bottom: 7, right: 7)
    }
}

class CapturedPhotoCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    func configure(image: UIImage) {
        self.imageView.image = image
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're calling `reloadData()` in your collection view controller at the moment when the images array is empty. Your `self.imgCollectionView.reloadData()` part of code is called at the moment when your `CapturedPhotoViewController` is being instantiated (`viewDidLoad`), and at that moment the array of the images is empty.

The easiest fix without making too much changes, would be to just call `reloadData()`, after the VC has been presented

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "CapturedPhotoViewController") as? CapturedPhotoViewController {
    vc.images.append(pickedIMG)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    vc.imgCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: thanks for comments and answers, however, I do not think it is a good approach or habit to call the `.reloadData()`  from another VC, as the `collectionView` hasn't finished dequeueing or the another VC hasn't been called yet, it causes problems for sure.. Nevertheless, I have tested it, came back to confirm that it doesn't work that way.. .  `collectionView` returns `nil` at this point.. . thanks anyways.. .